# Resolved 404 after successfulAuthentication using AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter of Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I have a problem: I am trying to implement an authentication based on two HEADER, a HMAC-SHA256 signed with the shared key of a merchant and a merchantId.
All the path that starts with /api/payment/** I want that are checked in this manner.

When I call my service in POST  /fcabpo/api/payment/hmac-validation
It seems that does authentication right because method successfulAuthentication gas bene called of my class that extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter is called but after It seems that call is forwarded to a GET to the context root /fcabpo and so I received a 404.

I wrote my class HMACAuthenticationProvider that extends AuthenticationProvider

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class HMACAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        HMACAuthenticationToken hmacAuthenticationToken = (HMACAuthenticationToken)authentication;
        String merchandId = hmacAuthenticationToken.getPrincipalMerchantId();
        HMACSha256Credential hmacSha256Credential = hmacAuthenticationToken.getHmacSha256Credential();
        // TODO check the hmac
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
        grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("MERCHANT"));
        Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(merchandId, hmacSha256Credential.getHmacSha256(), grantedAuthorities);
        return auth;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return HMACAuthenticationToken.class.equals(authentication);
    }

}
```

I wrote also a HMACRestSecurityFilter that extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter

```
@Slf4j
public class HMACRestSecurityFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    public static final String  HEADER_KEY_MERCHANT_ID  = "merchantId";
    public static final String  HMAC_SHA256                         = "HMAC-SHA256";
    public static final String  EPOCH_TIME                          = "EPOCH-TIME";

    public HMACRestSecurityFilter(RequestMatcher requiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher) {
        super(requiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher);
    }

    public HMACRestSecurityFilter(String defaultFilterProcessesUrl) {
        super(defaultFilterProcessesUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        MultiReadHttpServletRequest multiReadHttpServletRequest = ServletUtil.wrapRequest(request);
        String merchantId = multiReadHttpServletRequest.getHeader(HEADER_KEY_MERCHANT_ID);
        String hmacSha256 = multiReadHttpServletRequest.getHeader(HMAC_SHA256);
        String epochTimeStr = multiReadHttpServletRequest.getHeader(EPOCH_TIME);
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(merchantId) || StringUtils.isBlank(hmacSha256) || StringUtils.isBlank(epochTimeStr)) {
            unsuccessfulAuthentication(multiReadHttpServletRequest, response, new BadHMACAuthRequestException("Authentication attempt failed! Request missing mandatory headers."));
        }
        long epochTime = 0;
        try {
            epochTime = Long.parseLong(epochTimeStr);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            unsuccessfulAuthentication(multiReadHttpServletRequest, response, new BadHMACAuthRequestException("Authentication attempt failed! Request missing mandatory headers."));
        }
        HMACSha256Credential hmacSha256Credential = new HMACSha256Credential();
        byte[] content = multiReadHttpServletRequest.getInputStreamCopy();
        String contentString = new String(content, multiReadHttpServletRequest.getCharacterEncoding());
        hmacSha256Credential.setBody(contentString);
        hmacSha256Credential.setEpochTime(epochTime);
        hmacSha256Credential.setHmacSha256(hmacSha256);
        hmacSha256Credential.setHttpMethod(multiReadHttpServletRequest.getMethod());
        hmacSha256Credential.setUri(multiReadHttpServletRequest.getRequestURI());
        HMACAuthenticationToken hmacAuthenticationToken = new HMACAuthenticationToken(merchantId, hmacSha256Credential);
        return hmacAuthenticationToken;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)res;
        MultiReadHttpServletRequest multiReadHttpServletRequest = ServletUtil.wrapRequest(request);
        super.doFilter(multiReadHttpServletRequest, response, chain);
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);
    }

    @Override
    protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.unsuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, failed);
    }

}
```

and HMACAuthenticationToken that extends AbstractAuthenticationToken
and the class that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to configure path e filter

```
@Configuration
public class ActuatorSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/payment/**").hasAnyAuthority("MERCHANT").and().addFilterBefore(new HMACRestSecurityFilter("/api/payment/**"),
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll().and().csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

I don't what can be the problem and I don't find anything of useful to resolve on the web.

Comment: please enable spring security debug logs, and then post your full logs, startup logs and logs from the request, so that we can see what is loaded at startup, and how it logs your incoming request.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was call chain.doFilter(request, response); in successfulAuthentication

```
    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

And register a new RedirectStrategy

```
public class NoRedirectStrategy implements RedirectStrategy {

    @Override
    public void sendRedirect(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String url) throws IOException {}

}
```

The configuration class is:

```
package it.reply.pay.fcabpo.rs.util.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.HttpStatusEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestMatcher;

import it.reply.pay.fcabpo.rs.util.security.signature.SignatureAuthenticationProvider;
import it.reply.pay.fcabpo.rs.util.security.signature.SignatureResponseFilter;
import it.reply.pay.fcabpo.rs.util.security.signature.SignatureRestSecurityFilter;
import it.reply.pay.fcabpo.util.constants.ProjectConstants;
import it.reply.pay.fcabpo.util.enums.RoleEnum;

@Configuration
public class ProjectSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    public static final String                          PAYMENT_PATH_WILD_CARDS = ProjectConstants.Path.Payment.PAYMENT + "/**";

    @Autowired
    private SignatureAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    // Se viene aggiunta questa configurazione per AuthenticationManagerBuilder l'autenticatore viene chiamato 2 volte erroneamente in caso di errore
    // .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider) prima di addFilterBefore
    // verificare se è una configurazione necessaria quando ci sono più autenticatori
    // @Override
    // protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    // auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    // }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // al posto di .hasAnyAuthority(RoleEnum.ROLE_MERCHANT.name()) si puo' anche usare .authenticated() e poi sopra il metodo rest indicare quale sia il ruolo da usare @Secured("ROLE_USER")
        RequestMatcher paymReqMatcher = new AntPathRequestMatcher(PAYMENT_PATH_WILD_CARDS);
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().exceptionHandling().defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(forbiddenEntryPoint(),
            paymReqMatcher).and().addFilterBefore(signatureRestSecurityFilter(), AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class).authorizeRequests().antMatchers(PAYMENT_PATH_WILD_CARDS).hasAnyAuthority(
                RoleEnum.ROLE_MERCHANT.name()).and().csrf().disable().formLogin().disable().httpBasic().disable().logout().disable();

        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll().and().csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    FilterRegistrationBean<SignatureRestSecurityFilter> disableAutoRegistration(SignatureRestSecurityFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean<SignatureRestSecurityFilter> registration = new FilterRegistrationBean<SignatureRestSecurityFilter>(filter);
        // set as false to avoid multiple filter calls
        registration.setEnabled(false);
        return registration;
    }

    @Bean
    AuthenticationEntryPoint forbiddenEntryPoint() {
        return new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<SignatureResponseFilter> loggingFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean<SignatureResponseFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<SignatureResponseFilter>();

        registrationBean.setFilter(new SignatureResponseFilter());
        registrationBean.setOrder(1);
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns(ProjectConstants.Path.Payment.PAYMENT + "/*");

        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    SignatureRestSecurityFilter signatureRestSecurityFilter() throws Exception {
        SignatureRestSecurityFilter filter = new SignatureRestSecurityFilter(PAYMENT_PATH_WILD_CARDS);
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successHandler());
        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
        SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        successHandler.setRedirectStrategy(new NoRedirectStrategy());
        return successHandler;
    }

}
```